# JavaFX pass arguments

Tags: java, javafx

I create the following class:

```
    package sample;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextArea;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import vom.CAPlatform;

public class SecureCAController extends Application {

    private double xOffset;
    private double yOffset;
    public CAPlatform myAgent;
    public static boolean ready = false;

    public SecureCAController(CAPlatform caPlatform) {
        myAgent = caPlatform;
        System.out.println(myAgent.getAID());
    }

    public SecureCAController() {

    }

    public void show(){
        launch();
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));


        root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                xOffset = mouseEvent.getSceneX();
                yOffset = mouseEvent.getSceneY();
            }
        });


        root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                primaryStage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                primaryStage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() - yOffset);
            }
        });


        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setTitle("CA");
        Scene sceneNew = new Scene(root);
        sceneNew.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(sceneNew);
        primaryStage.show();
        ready = true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    public void setAgent(CAPlatform caPlatform) {
        myAgent = caPlatform;
    }

    @FXML
    private ImageView userArrow;
    @FXML private ImageView printerArrow;
    @FXML private ImageView crudArrow;
    @FXML private ImageView exitArrow;

    @FXML private AnchorPane userPanel;
    @FXML private AnchorPane printerPanel;
    @FXML private AnchorPane crudPanel;

    @FXML private JFXTextField userText;
    @FXML private JFXPasswordField passwordText;
    @FXML private JFXTextField AIDText;

    @FXML private JFXButton startButton;
    @FXML private JFXButton pendingButton;
    @FXML private JFXButton validateButton;
    @FXML private JFXButton validateRButton;

    @FXML private JFXTextArea PList;
    @FXML private JFXTextArea AreaList;


    public void onstartButton(ActionEvent event){
        if(userText.getText().isEmpty() || passwordText.getText().isEmpty()){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("ERROR");
            alert.setContentText("PLEASE INSERT USERNAME AND PASSWORD");
        }else{
            System.out.println(this.myAgent.getAID());
        }
    }

    public void onpendingButton(ActionEvent event){

    }

    public void onvalidateButton(ActionEvent event){
        if(AIDText.getText().isEmpty()){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("ERROR");
            alert.setContentText("PLEASE INSERT AN AID");
        }
    }

    public void onvalidateRButton(ActionEvent event){

    }



    public void onExitButtonClicked(MouseEvent event){
        Platform.exit();
        System.exit(0);
    }


    public void onUserButtonClicked(MouseEvent event){
        System.out.println("si");
        userPanel.setVisible(true);
        userArrow.setVisible(true);

        printerPanel.setVisible(false);
        crudPanel.setVisible(false);
        printerArrow.setVisible(false);
        crudArrow.setVisible(false);
        exitArrow.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void onPrinterButtonClicked(MouseEvent event){
        printerPanel.setVisible(true);
        printerArrow.setVisible(true);

        crudPanel.setVisible(false);
        userPanel.setVisible(false);
        userArrow.setVisible(false);
        crudArrow.setVisible(false);
        exitArrow.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void onCRUDButtonClicked(MouseEvent event){
        crudPanel.setVisible(true);
        crudArrow.setVisible(true);

        userPanel.setVisible(false);
        userArrow.setVisible(false);
        printerPanel.setVisible(false);
        printerArrow.setVisible(false);
        exitArrow.setVisible(false);
    }

}
```

In the secureCAController, initialize the agent and launch the application, but when i try to execute one method for example myAgent.getname() return null.

Anyone can help me? I dont know a lot of about javafx sorry if it is a dummy error.

myAgent is an object, that contains a lot of methods.

My fxml is the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextArea?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="474.0" prefWidth="562.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.SecureCAController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="562.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0f6b7d;">
         <children>
            <HBox prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="562.0">
               <children>
                  <Separator prefWidth="200.0" visible="false" />
                  <ImageView fitHeight="46.0" fitWidth="69.0" onMouseClicked="#onUserButtonClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Images/user.png" />
                     </image>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Separator prefWidth="200.0" visible="false" />
                  <ImageView fitHeight="46.0" fitWidth="69.0" onMouseClicked="#onPrinterButtonClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Images/print.png" />
                     </image>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Separator prefWidth="200.0" visible="false" />
                  <ImageView fitHeight="46.0" fitWidth="69.0" onMouseClicked="#onCRUDButtonClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Images/accept.png" />
                     </image>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Separator prefWidth="200.0" visible="false" />
                  <ImageView fitHeight="46.0" fitWidth="69.0" onMouseClicked="#onExitButtonClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Images/exit.png" />
                     </image>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Separator prefWidth="200.0" visible="false" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="userPanel" layoutY="86.0" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="562.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0f6b7d;">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane layoutX="20.0" layoutY="28.0" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="522.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="60.0" layoutY="126.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="     USER:">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="SansSerif Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label layoutX="57.0" layoutY="191.0" text="PASSWORD:">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="SansSerif Bold Italic" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="userText" layoutX="228.0" layoutY="126.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="236.0" promptText="Enter your username" />
                  <ImageView fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" layoutX="220.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Images/shelt.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <JFXPasswordField fx:id="passwordText" layoutX="228.0" layoutY="189.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="236.0" promptText="Enter your password" />
               </children>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
            </AnchorPane>
            <JFXButton fx:id="startButton" layoutX="203.0" layoutY="337.0" onAction="#onstartButton" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="157.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" text="Start">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <ImageView fx:id="userArrow" fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="90.0" layoutX="83.0" layoutY="59.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="180.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@Images/arrow.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fx:id="printerArrow" fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="90.0" layoutX="208.0" layoutY="59.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="180.0" visible="false">
         <image>
            <Image url="@Images/arrow.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fx:id="crudArrow" fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="90.0" layoutX="327.0" layoutY="59.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="180.0" visible="false">
         <image>
            <Image url="@Images/arrow.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fx:id="exitArrow" fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="90.0" layoutX="444.0" layoutY="59.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="180.0" visible="false">
         <image>
            <Image url="@Images/arrow.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="printerPanel" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="96.0" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="562.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0f6b7d;" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="86.0">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane layoutX="20.0" layoutY="28.0" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="522.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0">
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <children>
                  <Separator layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="522.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;" />
                  <Label layoutX="203.0" layoutY="2.0" text="Platform List" textAlignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="SansSerif Regular" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <JFXTextArea fx:id="AreaList" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="252.0" prefWidth="523.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <JFXButton fx:id="pendingButton" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="334.0" onAction="#onpendingButton" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="222.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" text="Pending Requests">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton fx:id="validateRButton" layoutX="320.0" layoutY="334.0" onAction="#onvalidateRButton" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="222.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" text="Validated Requests">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="crudPanel" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="106.0" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="562.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0f6b7d;" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="86.0">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane layoutX="20.0" layoutY="28.0" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="522.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0">
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <children>
                  <Separator layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="522.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;" />
                  <Label layoutX="184.0" layoutY="2.0" text="Pending Platforms" textAlignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="SansSerif Regular" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <JFXTextArea fx:id="PList" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="252.0" prefWidth="523.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <JFXButton fx:id="ValidateButton" layoutX="322.0" layoutY="333.0" onAction="#onvalidateButton" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="219.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" text="Validate">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXTextField fx:id="AIDText" focusColor="BLACK" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="344.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="290.0" unFocusColor="WHITE" />
            <Label layoutX="19.0" layoutY="333.0" text="PLATFORM AID:" textFill="WHITE" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you also post your FXML File and your CAPlatform Class?

Comment: It’s pretty much always a mistake to use the same class for the application Life cycle (I.e. the `Application` subclass) as you use for your controller. Anyway, though, both the instance created for you when you call `Application.launch()` and the instance of the controller created when the FXML file is loaded are created by invoking the zero-argument constructor. That constructor doesn’t initialize `myAgent`, so it will be null (in both cases).

Comment: @James_D and its possible to initialize this object?

Comment: The problem is that you should split the Controller Class and the Application Class apart. Then the Controller Class implements Initailizable and in the intitialize method you can initialize myAgent..

Comment: @micpog90 i just divide the controller and the application, but how can i acces to the myAgent?

Comment: If needed, you can initialize it in the `start()` method and [pass it to the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml). Or, if it’s ok to have a different instance for each controller that’s created, just initialize it in the controller using one of the two ways shown in the answer by @micpog90

Comment: I have added to the answer how you could pass myAgent from the Application to the Controller..

Answer (score 1):

I have cleaned up your project a little:

Your Aplication Class:

```
package vom;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author mipog
 */
public class SecureCA extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SecureCA.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Your FXML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextArea?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="474.0" prefWidth="562.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="vom.SecureCAController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="562.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0f6b7d;">
         <children>
            <HBox prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="562.0">
               <children>
                  <Separator prefWidth="200.0" visible="false" />
                  <ImageView fitHeight="46.0" fitWidth="69.0" onMouseClicked="#onUserButtonClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Images/user.png" />
                     </image>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Separator prefWidth="200.0" visible="false" />
                  <ImageView fitHeight="46.0" fitWidth="69.0" onMouseClicked="#onPrinterButtonClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Images/print.png" />
                     </image>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Separator prefWidth="200.0" visible="false" />
                  <ImageView fitHeight="46.0" fitWidth="69.0" onMouseClicked="#onCRUDButtonClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Images/accept.png" />
                     </image>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Separator prefWidth="200.0" visible="false" />
                  <ImageView fitHeight="46.0" fitWidth="69.0" onMouseClicked="#onExitButtonClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Images/exit.png" />
                     </image>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Separator prefWidth="200.0" visible="false" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="userPanel" layoutY="86.0" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="562.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0f6b7d;">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane layoutX="20.0" layoutY="28.0" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="522.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="60.0" layoutY="126.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="     USER:">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="SansSerif Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label layoutX="57.0" layoutY="191.0" text="PASSWORD:">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="SansSerif Bold Italic" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="userText" layoutX="228.0" layoutY="126.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="236.0" promptText="Enter your username" />
                  <ImageView fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" layoutX="220.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Images/shelt.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <JFXPasswordField fx:id="passwordText" layoutX="228.0" layoutY="189.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="236.0" promptText="Enter your password" />
               </children>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
            </AnchorPane>
            <JFXButton fx:id="startButton" layoutX="203.0" layoutY="337.0" onAction="#onstartButton" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="157.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" text="Start">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <ImageView fx:id="userArrow" fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="90.0" layoutX="83.0" layoutY="59.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="180.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@Images/arrow.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fx:id="printerArrow" fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="90.0" layoutX="208.0" layoutY="59.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="180.0" visible="false">
         <image>
            <Image url="@Images/arrow.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fx:id="crudArrow" fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="90.0" layoutX="327.0" layoutY="59.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="180.0" visible="false">
         <image>
            <Image url="@Images/arrow.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fx:id="exitArrow" fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="90.0" layoutX="444.0" layoutY="59.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="180.0" visible="false">
         <image>
            <Image url="@Images/arrow.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="printerPanel" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="96.0" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="562.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0f6b7d;" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="86.0">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane layoutX="20.0" layoutY="28.0" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="522.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0">
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <children>
                  <Separator layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="522.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;" />
                  <Label layoutX="203.0" layoutY="2.0" text="Platform List" textAlignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="SansSerif Regular" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <JFXTextArea fx:id="AreaList" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="252.0" prefWidth="523.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <JFXButton fx:id="pendingButton" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="334.0" onAction="#onpendingButton" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="222.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" text="Pending Requests">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton fx:id="validateRButton" layoutX="320.0" layoutY="334.0" onAction="#onvalidateRButton" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="222.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" text="Validated Requests">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="crudPanel" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="106.0" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="562.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0f6b7d;" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="86.0">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane layoutX="20.0" layoutY="28.0" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="522.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0">
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <children>
                  <Separator layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="522.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;" />
                  <Label layoutX="184.0" layoutY="2.0" text="Pending Platforms" textAlignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="SansSerif Regular" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <JFXTextArea fx:id="PList" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="252.0" prefWidth="523.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <JFXButton fx:id="ValidateButton" layoutX="322.0" layoutY="333.0" onAction="#onvalidateButton" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="219.0" style="-fx-background-color: #85c0cc;" text="Validate">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXTextField fx:id="AIDText" focusColor="BLACK" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="344.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="290.0" unFocusColor="WHITE" />
            <Label layoutX="19.0" layoutY="333.0" text="PLATFORM AID:" textFill="WHITE" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And your Controller Class:

```
package vom;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextArea;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

/**
 *
 * @author mipog
 */
public class SecureCAController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ImageView userArrow;
    @FXML
    private ImageView printerArrow;
    @FXML
    private ImageView crudArrow;
    @FXML
    private ImageView exitArrow;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane userPanel;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane printerPanel;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane crudPanel;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField userText;
    @FXML
    private JFXPasswordField passwordText;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField AIDText;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton startButton;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton pendingButton;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton validateButton;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton validateRButton;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextArea PList;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextArea AreaList;

    //You can either here init your myAgent or in the initialize method
    CAPlatform myAgent = new CAPlatform();

    @FXML
    private void onstartButton() {
        if (userText.getText().isEmpty() || passwordText.getText().isEmpty()) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("ERROR");
            alert.setContentText("PLEASE INSERT USERNAME AND PASSWORD");
        } else {
            System.out.println(this.myAgent.getAID());
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void onpendingButton() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void onvalidateButton() {
        if (AIDText.getText().isEmpty()) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("ERROR");
            alert.setContentText("PLEASE INSERT AN AID");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void onvalidateRButton() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void onExitButtonClicked() {
        Platform.exit();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @FXML
    private void onUserButtonClicked() {
        System.out.println("si");
        userPanel.setVisible(true);
        userArrow.setVisible(true);

        printerPanel.setVisible(false);
        crudPanel.setVisible(false);
        printerArrow.setVisible(false);
        crudArrow.setVisible(false);
        exitArrow.setVisible(false);
    }

    @FXML
    private void onPrinterButtonClicked() {
        printerPanel.setVisible(true);
        printerArrow.setVisible(true);

        crudPanel.setVisible(false);
        userPanel.setVisible(false);
        userArrow.setVisible(false);
        crudArrow.setVisible(false);
        exitArrow.setVisible(false);
    }

    @FXML
    private void onCRUDButtonClicked() {
        crudPanel.setVisible(true);
        crudArrow.setVisible(true);

        userPanel.setVisible(false);
        userArrow.setVisible(false);
        printerPanel.setVisible(false);
        printerArrow.setVisible(false);
        exitArrow.setVisible(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // Here you init you myAgent
        myAgent = new CAPlatform();
    }

}
```

Maybe this will help you a little..

if you want to pass myAgent to the Controller Class from the Application Class. Your Application class has to look like the following. And you have to make a setter for the myAgent variable in the Controller Class.

```
package vom;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author mipog
 */
public class SecureCA extends Application {

    CAPlatform myAgent = new CAPlatform();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SecureCA.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        SecureCAController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMyAgent(myAgent);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @micpog90. but this solution create a new caagent and not that i want.It would be very difficult to do as I say?

Comment: You can pass the 'caagent' from the application to the controller if you have initialized it there. Unfortunately, I have not your whole project, so I have no idea where you init the myAgent variable..

Comment: In the secureCAController i create the function to pass the agent and initialize the var, if i print it, its correct but when i save it and then reference it is null :(

Comment: how i should call the Application from the CAPlatform?

Comment: What to you mean with save it?

Comment: I just fix it, THANK YOU SO MUCH @micpog90 really, thanks for everything